# Using {{URL('')}} in HTML on Controller Laravel

Tags: laravel

**This my Controller :**

```
public function search (Request $request){
    foreach($data as $row){
        $output .= '
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="view/'.$row->random.'/'.$row->slug.'"
            </a>
            '.$row->namaproduk.'
          </td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
```

My question is, if I'm click the title product ( <a href= ) will direct to :

```
localhost:800/cat/random/slug
```

What i want the link must direct to

```
localhost:800/random/slug
```

In normally, if in blade we using : **{{ URL('') }}**
Example :

```
<h1><a class="lik" href="{{URL('view/'.$produk->string.'/'.$produk->slug.'')}}">{{$produk->namaproduk}}</a></h1>
```

How i can using {{ URL('') }} in $output .= '  ';?

Thanks you .

Comment: try to add ./ after your url like this if it does not work add ../

<h1><a class="lik" href="./{{URL('view/'.$produk->string.'/'.$produk->slug.'')}}">{{$produk->namaproduk}}</a></h1>

Comment: @Abdulrahman Thanks you, i was tried using '.url('').' and worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I'm tried using like this, maybe can help you all :

> **My Controller**

```
   public function search (Request $request){
foreach($data as $row){
    $output .= '
    <tr>
    <td>
     <a href="'.url('view/'.$row->random.'/'.$row->slug.'/').'"</a>'.$row- >namaproduk.'
   </td>
    </tr>';
}}
```

Comment: Make sure to mark your solution as accepted (✅), so that others know that the problem has been solved and that this was the solution that worked for you.